# Click to reveal div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a more efficient way of creating this function with Javascript.

As you can see in [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qzfesw5d/), the first block works fine but not the second block. I plan to roll this out across hundreds of categories, so wonder if there's a neater solution here.

```
const btn = document.getElementById("category36SeeMore");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = this.id.replace('SeeMore', '')
  document.querySelectorAll('.' + id).forEach(el=>el.style.display = 'block')
});

.category36 {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: Skyblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
  border-right: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
}

<p>
<a href="#" id="category36SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category36">
test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
test
</div>


<hr>

<p>
<a href="#" id="category37SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category37">
test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
test
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/qzfesw5d/

Is jQuery a better approach here? We use that on the site already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target all the elements and loop through them to attach the event. You can either use *attribute starts with selector* or use a common *class* to target the elements:

```js
const btnList = document.querySelectorAll("a[id^=category");
btnList.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = this.id.replace('SeeMore', '')
    document.querySelectorAll('.' + id).forEach(el=>el.style.display = 'block')
  });
});
```

```css
.category36, .category37 {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: Skyblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
  border-right: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" id="category36SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category36">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<hr>

<p>
  <a href="#" id="category37SeeMore">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category37">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>

<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using plain javascript (like your example) you could apply the following logic:

- Give a specific class to all your container like `category-container`
- Instead of selection ONE using the ID, select them ALL using the classname
- Loop over them to add the event
- Make sure that the event will change the display of the children of the current parent

Adding new categories will not break anything. This should be entirely scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery might make things a little simpler. Here is one approach with plain JavaScript.

```
const categoryCount = 36
for (let i = 0; i < categoryCount; i++) {
  const btn = document.getElementById(`category${i+1}SeeMore`)
  if (btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.querySelectorAll(`.category${i+1}`)
        .forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change all `...SeeMore` elements to class and then add `data-*` attribute to all to point to the collection that you want to show like:

```
<a href="#" class="SeeMore" data-id="36">See more</a>
```

Then loop through each class and on click of any seemore, you can get the id easily using:

```
const id = this.dataset.id
```

and then easily show the collections divs like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.category' + id).forEach(el=>el.style.display = 'block')
```

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".SeeMore");
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = this.dataset.id
    document.querySelectorAll('.category' + id).forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block')
  });
});
```

```css
.category36, .category37 {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: Skyblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
  border-right: 1px solid #F9F2D6;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" class="SeeMore" data-id="36">See more</a>
</p>

<div class="category36">
  test
</div>
<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
<div class="category36" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>


<hr>

<p>
  <a href="#" class="SeeMore" data-id="37">See more</a>
</p>
<div class="category37">
  test
</div>
<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
<div class="category37" style="display:none;">
  test
</div>
```